# Python 3.8.5 and IDL8.8

Tags: python, development-environment, python-idle

I'm try run idl code in python

```
from idlpy import IDL
IDL.run("e = envi()")
...
IDL.run("flaash_obj = obj_new('flaash_batch', /anc_delete)")
IDL.run("flaash_obj->SetProperty, $")
...
```

Why console show

```
 File "C:\Users\timer\Desktop\1\FLAASH.py", line 42, in <module>
    IDL.run("flaash_obj->SetProperty, $")

  File "C:\Program Files\Harris\ENVI56\IDL88\lib\bridges\idlpy.py", line 502, in run
    raise IDLError('\n' + output)

IDLError: 
% Keyword !NULL not allowed in call to: FLAASH_BATCH::SETPROPERTY
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$
```

The IDL code can run with command line and not error
[IDL command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhlZp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run it into Python 3.6.5 and IDL 8.5, have no the error.